# Minimizing a multivariable function

Tags: matlab, minimization

I'm aware of the fminsearch function, but it only seems to be able to solve for one variable.

If my function looks like f(x,y,z) and I want to find the values of x,y,z that gives the lowest result, how would I do this in MatLab?  The complexity of f would make it unreasonably difficult to calculate the partial derivatives.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: in fminsearch documentation, see example 1...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

fminsearch is multivariable, for example:

```
a = fminsearch(@(x)((x(1)-1)^2+(x(2)-2)^2), [0,0]);
```

the parameter passed to the objective function can be a vector, just be sure to specify the x0 parameter (the second parameter in fminsearch) to the right size.

Comment: So in this example, @(x) represents an array with 2 elements x(1) and x(2).  What then does [0,0] represent?  start x(1) at 0 and x(2) at 0?  Thanks!

Comment: exactly, `[0,0]` is the starting point of the algorithm, its size determines the number of variables in the optimization

Comment: just to clarify, @(x) is an inline anonymous function deceleration, the example above is a shorthand for:
`function y = f(x)
y = ((x(1)-1)^2+(x(2)-2)^2)`
...
`a = fminsearch(f, [0,0]);`

Comment: I'm getting an error with: min = fminsearch(GetJointMle, [0,0,0]);
??? Input argument "x" is undefined.
Error in ==> GetJointMle at 5
alpha = x(1);

Comment: my mistake, there should be apostrophes around the function name, like so `min = fminsearch('GetJointMle', [0,0,0]);`. with out the apostrophes you are calling GetJointMle with no parameters and passing the result as the first parameter to fminsearch...

Comment: I also got it to work putting an "@" in front of GetJointMle.  Thanks for your assistance!  MatLab is becoming less frustrating :)